# Javascript Resize on First Run

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I have a javascript resize function that works when I resize the browser, but How can I get it to resize my content if I start my browser window at a certain size as well ? You can see this in code pen http://codepen.io/celli/pen/pyMMWe my content will resize when we adjust the browser window--However if you refresh the codePen with your browser starting at a smaller size (smaller that 840px) then the content is not "pre" resized. How can I add code to make that happen ?

```js
var maxWidth  = $('#outer').width();
var maxHeight = $('#outer').height();

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

// media query
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 828px)");
mediaQuery.addListener(setAnimation);

// First run
setAnimation(mediaQuery);

function setAnimation(mediaQuery) {
  if (mediaQuery.matches) {
    // resize func below
    var maxWidth  = $('#outer').width();
    var maxHeight = $('#outer').height();

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $(window).resize(function(evt) {
      var $window = $(window);
      var width = $window.width();
      var height = $window.height();
      var scale;

      // early exit
      if(width >= windowWidth && height >= windowHeight) {
        $('#outer').css({'-webkit-transform': ''});
        $('#wrappie').css({ width: '', height: '' });
        return;
      }

      scale = Math.min(width/windowWidth);

      $('#outer').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
      $('#wrappie').css({ width: maxWidth * scale, height: maxHeight * scale });
    });
  } else {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way, convert it into a function. Replace:

```
$(window).resize(function(evt) {
  var $window = $(window);
  var width = $window.width();
  var height = $window.height();
  var scale;

  // early exit
  if(width >= windowWidth && height >= windowHeight) {
    $('#outer').css({'-webkit-transform': ''});
    $('#wrappie').css({ width: '', height: '' });
    return;
  }

  scale = Math.min(width/windowWidth);

  $('#outer').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
  $('#wrappie').css({ width: maxWidth * scale, height: maxHeight * scale });
});
```

With:

```
function reszEvt(evt) {
  var $window = $(window);
  var width = $window.width();
  var height = $window.height();
  var scale;

  // early exit
  if(width >= windowWidth && height >= windowHeight) {
    $('#outer').css({'-webkit-transform': ''});
    $('#wrappie').css({ width: '', height: '' });
    return;
  }

  scale = Math.min(width/windowWidth);

  $('#outer').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
  $('#wrappie').css({ width: maxWidth * scale, height: maxHeight * scale });
}
```

And give these two:

```
$(window).resize(reszEvt);
$(reszEvt); // Or the below:
$(document).ready(reszEvt);
```

**CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOmmjo**

Comment: humm, I don't see that working. I adjusted my codePen, but I didn't see the result when I refresh my browser at a small window size (under 840px) ... I'd like it to resize to the window width, even if I am not actively resizing my browser window... can you fork my CodePen, and let me know if you see it working ?

Comment: I am able to see it working... That's why I posted it as an answer. `:)` May be you need to bring the event handlers outside? You are executing the `setAnimation()` right?

Comment: It works when I resize the window like before, but if I reload the page (in Chrome) at a small browser window size, like let's say 500px... you get the horizontal scroll bar, and you can see it hasn't resized to the width of my browser window.  I have the updated code in this codePen http://codepen.io/celli/pen/pyMMWe

Comment: Thanks Praveen, Let me know if you see a way to do it when I first load the page if my window width is less than 840px--it resizes when I resize my window, but it doesn't confirm to the window size when I first load my page if the window width is less than 840px.

Comment: Hi Praveen, I also tried wrapping the entire function in a function like this:  $(window).on("load resize",function(e){
but I still couldn't get it to resize/scale to the window when I first load the page, if the page width is less than 840px... There has got to be an easy way that I am missing... can you help ?